# Compiling an MPI program with mingw and MPICH2 in eclipse juno

Tags: c, windows, eclipse, mpi, openmpi

Ive been trying to setup **mpich2** to compile some programs using MPI on windows 7. The problem that I encounter is that it **wont create the binary files** when I build a project.
I use the stadard mpi program to test (hello world) and I get this message after building it:

> 13:33:29 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project mpitest ****
>   Info: Internal Builder is used for build mpiCC "-IC:\MPICH2\include"
>
> ### -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\mpitest.o" "..\src\mpitest.c"
>
> The Open MPI wrapper compiler was unable to find the specified
>   compiler cl.exe in your PATH.
>
> Note that this compiler was either specified at configure time or in one of several 
>   possible environment variables.
>
> ---
>
> 13:33:29 Build Finished (took 78ms)

I tried to search for cl.exe but it doesn't exist. I have to say that I also installed openMPI but I didn't use it cause the cluster that I am gonna target run the program is using MPICH2. I have already installed 32bit minGW, 32bit MPICH2 and 32bit openMPI. 
Is it normal to not create binaries since i run the .c file in the cluster? If its normal how am i going to check if the program is ok even for 1 process?
Thanks in advance! Cheers!

Comment: @SachinPrasad Any idea who i may ask help from this issue? Seems that MPI usage is very low and people cant help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by luck... In the project preferences, select C/C++ build-> Tool Chain editor-> choose cygwin and its done. For some reason i had mingw in that option and wouldnt create binaries, i suppose it needs some other tools that can be found only in the cygwin and not mingw... Still trying to set it and run on the cluster... so many options :/